# Use Neo4j algorithms from Java and Tinkerpop

Tags: java, neo4j, tinkerpop

I am using Neo4J as my underlying GraphDB, with Tinkerpop 3.3.1 on top in my Java application.  I create the Graph in Java with *Neo4JGraph.open ("/tmp/filename")*, and then from there I only use the Tinkerpop Java API to create nodes, edges and run traversals.

I want to perform a Dijkstra shortest path on my Tinkerpop graph.  Neo4J, which is my underlying GraphDB, has this algorithm built in, so I would like to use it.  I use the make this call to get the Neo4J graph, and get a few Neo4JNode types from it.

```
Neo4jGraphAPI neo4J = this.graphPV.getBaseGraph();
Neo4jNode start = neo4J.getNodeById(1);
Neo4jNode end = neo4J.getNodeById(2);
```

This works, but now I'm not sure what to do next.  I figured I would pass these nodes to the Neo4J pathfinder, but the *findSinglePath* method takes a *Node* type, not a Tinkerpop based *Neo4JNode*.  I tried casting, that threw an exception.  Can I convert the Tinkerpop Neo4JNode into a Neo4J Node type that the underlying Neo4J API will accept ?

```
dijkstraPathFinder = GraphAlgoFactory.dijkstra(expander, costEvaluator );
WeightedPath path = dijkstraPathFinder.findSinglePath((Node)start, (Node)end );
```

Results in:

> WARNING: service exception java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.impl.Neo4jNodeImpl cannot be cast to
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.Node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Neo4jNodeImpl` and `Neo4jRelationshipImpl` both extend `Neo4jEntityImpl`, which has a public `getEntity()` method that returns the native neo4j `Node`/`Relationship`.

Unfortunately, `getEntity()` is not in the `Neo4jEntity` interface (and is therefore not in the `Neo4jNode` and `Neo4jRelationship` interfaces). So, to use `getEntity()`, your project will have to add a dependency on the [impl module](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl) and use a class cast. For example:

```
Neo4jGraphAPI neo4J = this.graphPV.getBaseGraph();
Neo4jNode start = neo4J.getNodeById(1);
Node nativeStart = ((Neo4jNodeImpl)start).getEntity();
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to depend on the impl module, there is a less performant option. You can use the `Neo4jEntity.getId()` method to get the native ID for the underlying neo4j Node/Relationship, and then perform a neo4j query to get that Node/Relationship.